# Java AST Parser - get full type of parameter, external project

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, types, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm creating a program (not in Eclipse) where the user inputs a directory of source code, and I parse through that code. When it comes to a method, I want to be able to pull the full parameter type. Example: from `protected void onCreate(Bundle)`, I should be able to pull `android.os.Bundle`. This is my code to activate the binding:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
parser.setUnitName(file.getName());  // name of file (Apple.java)
parser.setEnvironment(new String[] {""}, new String[] {""}, new String[] {"UTF-8"}, true);
parser.setSource(str.toCharArray());  // source code in file Apple.java
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);

parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

In the debugger, I'm able to confirm that the binding was activated, but it claims that Bundle's type is {MissingTypeBinding}. I am able to pull the full type when I pass the source code of the project I'm writing (so the parser is able to parse its own source code and pull the type names). So my question is, what am I missing to pull the full type from other source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't know where to look for types in order to create those bindings. Look at the JavaDoc for [#setResolveBindings()](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html#setResolveBindings-boolean-):

> Binding information is obtained from the Java model. This means that the compilation unit must be located relative to the Java model. This happens automatically when the source code comes from either setSource(ICompilationUnit) or setSource(IClassFile). When source is supplied by setSource(char[]), **the location must be established explicitly by setting an environment** using setProject(IJavaProject) or setEnvironment(String[], String[], String[], boolean) and a unit name setUnitName(String). Note that the compiler options that affect doc comment checking may also affect whether any bindings are resolved for nodes within doc comments.

Comment: What would I put for the class path for setEnvironment if the given source code doesn't include jar files or anything like that? I get the code from decompiling apks, so all I really know is the file structure.

Comment: I don't expect it would be able to read dex class files, but I expect that the standard Android runtime classes are readable..

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean? The source code would be the class path?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I added the runtime classes like you suggested and it worked. Thank you very much!